# Change the development website to live website in apache server

Tags: wordpress, apache, server, phpmyadmin, localhost

I tried to change my development website to live from last weeks but all not working.

The steps I done within the localhost apache server

1. Change the functions.php.

```
from

update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://dev.web.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://dev.web.com' );

to 

update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://new.web.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://new.web.com' );
```

2. Change the url of the wp_options in phpmyadmin.
3. Update the line in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','https://new.web.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://new.web.com');
```

Even I done all steps, I still cannot go into the website with new url. When i login to https://dev.web.com, the alignment are different and all hyperlink are link to the https://new.web.com.
Same as the wordpress able to login but looks like missing the css and javascript, (not dropdown function and the images corrupted).

Is that anyway to fix my issue?

Comment: You need to replace all dev URL to LIVE URL.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed.

I go to the hostfile in the server, change the previous hardcoded `https://dev.web.com` to `https://new.web.com`.

After that I use the method as Vel comment above, this plugin really faster my progress to change all the old url to new url. Other old url in the pages had to manual change all of it.